# Maximum Scale Factor for Text in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

For dynamic Text views, how day you set the maximum font size?
I know you can use .minimumScaleFactor to set the bottom limit. But is there a way to do this for the maximum size?

Answer (score -1):

max size is 100 now.

```
  Text(" String ")
    .font(.system(size: 100))
    .minimumScaleFactor(0.01)
    .lineLimit(1)
```